# How to Automate the Start-up Process of a Microsoft Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform Software Application?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch-file, automation, uwp

I would like to automate the start-up process of a Microsoft Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform software application.

According to [this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-automatically-launch-windows-universal-apps/a15987f1-224f-4b4b-bdba-c5663b3bc8b5), this issue is still not feasible without resorting to a workaround.

The workaround refers to the writing of a batch file that uses the Microsoft Windows PowerShell integrated shell-scripting environment in order to start that particular software application.

However, there is no straightforward path toward that particular software application within the `C:\Windows\SystemApps\` folder.

Any clues?

**Update after the comments and the first two answers that have already been provided below:**

The app is called as "*Weather*". Its long name seems to be "*Microsoft MSN Bing Weather*".

The answer that presents an automated solution based on the Microsoft PowerShell Integrated Shell-Scripting Environment is presented below.

A simple manual work-around is the following one:

1. Using the *Start Menu* (and **not** the *Start Screen* that covers the whole desktop view as in a full-screen mode), drag-and-drop the "*Weather*" tile on the desktop view.
2. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys-combination in order to pop up the "*Run*" dialog box.
3. Type `shell:startup` and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
4. Copy the "*Weather*" shortcut from the desktop view inside the `StartUp` folder.

Comment: what is the `particular software application`? [*grin*]

Comment: Good idea, @Lee_Dailey . Why keep it generic? It is the _Microsoft MSN Weather_ static software application. According to [the File.Net platform](https://www.file.net/process/microsoft.msn.weather.exe.html), its executable binary file should be called as `Microsoft.MSN.Weather.Exe` and stored _"in a subfolder of"_ `C:\Program Files\ `  _"(common is"_ `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ ` _"[...])"_. However, somehow I see no `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ ` folder on the machines that I am currently accessing. I have searched for the file on the entire `C:\ ` root folders on them.

Comment: thank you for the info! [*grin*] it looks like you have two answers to the weirdness of MS store apps. glad to know that things look do-able.

Comment: I totally agree with you, @Lee_Dailey. The UWP's have been a strange addition to the Windows world since their initial design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows store apps have a few quirks, but can be dealt with. Powershell refers to windows store apps as `AppxPackages`, but a package can have more than one app inside it, so we also need to check the `AppxManifest.xml` file to get more information.

First you'll need the package name, you can find it by dragging a shortcut to your desktop, then checking the properties > Targettype (you only need enough to have a unique name):

[image: TargetType screenshot]

In Powershell now, we get the package - you can find the package name by dragging a shortcut to your desktop, then checking the properties > Targettype:

```
$pkg = Get-AppxPackage *Communication*
```

Then we get the XML data of its manifest:

```
$manifest = [xml](get-content "$($pkg.InstallLocation)/AppxManifest.xml")
```

Then we get the package ID from within the XML:

```
$ID = $manifest.Package.Applications.Application.id
```

For our sanity, we check to make sure we only have one app ID:

```
if ($id.count -gt 1) {Write-Error "Found more than one app ID in package!: $id";break}
```

In my case, I have more than one, so I'll specify the ID manually:

```
$ID = 'microsoft.windowslive.calendar'
```

And finally, we launch the app:

```
Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList "shell:appsfolder\$($pkg.PackageFamilyName)!$id"
```

Or as a single script:

```
$pkg = get-appxpackage *Calculator*
$manifest = [xml](get-content "$($pkg.InstallLocation)/AppxManifest.xml")
$id = $manifest.Package.Applications.Application.id
if ($id.count -gt 1) {Write-Error "Found more than one app ID in package!: $id";break}
Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList "shell:appsfolder\$($pkg.PackageFamilyName)!$id"
```

**Please Note:** this has to run as the current logged-in user.

Comment: Can you believe it, @user19702? I was so stuck with using the Start Screen in the full screen mode, that I simply could not think about making a shortcut of a Metro tile of a Microsoft Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform static software application on the desktop view. Now I am back to the regular Start Menu. I have nicely created the shortcut. I wonder why the `$pkg = Get-AppxPackage *BingWeather*` PowerShell command does not output anything.

Comment: Strange. I have tested the `$pkg = Get-AppxPackage *BingWeather*` PowerShell command on two other machines and it _still_ does not return anything. Maybe it is a special app or it has been renamed recently. Who knows?

Comment: Can you believe it again, @user19702? I was so fixed upon the usage of batch files, of shell-scripts and generally of automation tools, that I could not see the fact that I could _simply_ copy the shortcut from the desktop view inside the `shell:startup` folder. It was _that_ simple.

Comment: @MihaiDobrescu The command doesn't return anything because it's writing the output to the `$pkg` variable. Also, the command you have in the comment on the other answer was only missing the `!` and the Package Name. It sounds like you got what you needed though.

Comment: What was I thinking, @user19702? God only knows. Of course that `$pkg = Get-AppxPackage *BingWeather*` is only an assignment PowerShell command. If you mean that the other comment should have contained the `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.BingWeather` command, then unfortunately it is _still_ producing the Documents library folder.

Comment: Also, @user19702, I have tested the 5 Source Lines of Code that you have named "_as a single script_" and they are nicely both starting either the "_Calculator_" or the "_Weather_" apps, if I swap the "`*Calculator*`" with the "`*BingWeather*`" character strings. If you include in your answer an MS-DOS/Microsoft Windows 10 Batch Commands Processing File ("`*.BAT`") that starts the PowerShell script, then I shall award this answer to you. I am too overwhelmed right now and apparently I am making very little and stupid mistakes. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: Apparently, @user19702, the `Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList` version of the PowerShell command does the trick, instead of the plain `explorer.exe`-based version. I bet that this is the best answer, once it becomes refined a little bit. Cheers for your good intuition.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong, @user19702. With your 5 Source Lines of Code, I can nicely produce the pop-up of either the "_Calculator_" app or of the "_Weather_" app. However, why does the `Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList "shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.BingWeather"` PowerShell one-liner produce the _Documents_ library folder window? It _simply_ deludes me.

Comment: @MihaiDobrescu I think you've misunderstood what comes after the `!`, the `$id` for bing weather is simply `app`. For me, this means I can create a desktop shortcut (instead of a batch file) and set the Path to the below, it starts BingWeather: `powershell.exe -c Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList "shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"`

Comment: It has not been a matter of misunderstanding, @user19702. It has rather been an issue of insufficient debugging. With `$pkg = get-appxpackage *Weather*;Write-Output $pkg.PackageFamilyName`, I can clearly see that the `$pkg.PackageFamilyName` is `Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe`. With `$manifest = [xml](get-content "$($pkg.InstallLocation)/AppxManifest.xml");$id = manifest.Package.Applications.Application.id;Write-Output $id`, I can clearly see that the `$id` is `App`.

Comment: I have just tested and, indeed, from within the _Run_ dialog box, the `powershell.exe -c Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList "shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"` command starts the _Weather_ app. Now I can see that the already-created desktop shortcut to the _Weather_ app already contains as its `Target:` field the `Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App` character string. It makes little sense to create another shortcut using a PowerShell call.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a UWP Application like this:

```
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\<PackageFamilyName>!<PackageName>
```

If you run the following command in PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select-Object PackageFamilyName, Name
```

You'll get the `PackageFamilyName` and the `PackageName` returned. which you then can use in the command mentioned above. For example if you want to start the Windows Store:

```
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WindowsStore
```

You could then write your own `Start-AppxPackage` function (it's a mystery to me why there is no native cmdlet for this yet)

```
Function Start-AppxPackage {
    
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$PackageFamilyName,
        [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$Name
    )

    Process {
        $Invoke = "explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\{0}!{1}" -f $PackageFamilyName, $Name
        Invoke-Expression $Invoke   
    }
}
```

and then you can simply use it like this for example:

```
Get-AppxPackage *photos* | Start-AppxPackage
```

You can also Start multiple apps at once:

```
Get-AppxPackage | ? {($_.Name -like '*photos*') -or ($_.Name -like '*store*')} | Start-AppxPackage
```

This command can then be included in a startup script or something similar

However, to be honest, this seems to be super buggy this starting shell apps via explorer. after a while it only opened the explorer on my documents instead of starting the correct shell app.

Comment: For the moment, the `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe` command starts the Documents library. I have to dig further into your answer. "_Simply_" seems to be a misnomer here.

Comment: As advised by @user19702, the correct PowerShell command should have been the following one: `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.BingWeather`, @SimonS. _Still_, it is producing the same Documents library folder instead of starting up the app.

Comment: @MihaiDobrescu This is the exact same as I wrote. you just need to find out the PackageFamilyName, the PackageName and put that into the command

Comment: I had the impression that `PackageFamilyName` is `Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe` and that `PackageName` is `Microsoft.BingWeather`, @SimonS. If they are both correct, then the `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.BingWeather` command is also correct. However, it is _still_ producing the _Documents_ library folder window instead of starting up the app.

Comment: Also, in the sentence "_after a while it only opened the explorer on my documents instead of starting the correct shell app._", the part "_after a while_" is not true in my case, @SimonS. The `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.BingWeather` PowerShell command has _always_ started the "_File Explorer_" app on my machine.

Comment: My mistake, @SimonS. The correct PowerShell one-liner is actually `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`, as pointed out by @user19702, and not `explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.BingWeather`, as it appears in my previous comment to you. So your answer is actually as good as his. I have to thank you, as well, for providing this automation solution for this question to me. Cheers!